Showing Network Host Unavailable in CMD
I'm working on a Vue.js project, and when I run the development server using npm run serve, the app starts successfully on http://localhost:8080/. However, the network is shown as "unavailable" your text
I tried accessing the app using the IP address of my machine on the network (e.g., http://:8080/), but it didn't work.

Have you tried restarting the server, does the problem still persist after restart?

Please, don't spam tags. You didn't mention your setup, this is what's important, not Vue. It looks like Vue CLI (not the same as Vue) but the question should say this. See stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . If that's the case, please, list vue.config.js. It's possible that the config is wrong, but most likely that it's "unavailable" means what it says, there was no network adapter detected at the time when the server was started. It likely has to be ipv4 for compatibility, not just v6. Make sure you enabled wifi, etc
